# Query selector order in Angular Animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

If I have 3 `div` in my container and I want to use the [query](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) from the API to grab those `div` and animate them in combination with `stagger`. How to bring an order to the animation?

For example:

```
<div id="slides-container"
     [@slide]="currentSlideIndex"
     @entering>

  <div id="previous-slide">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="next-slide">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="active-slide">
    ...

  </div>

</div>
```

Using this query, what would be the order of the animation? and how to change it?

```
query('#next-slide, #active-slide, #previous-slide', [
    style({
      transform: 'translateX(0)',
      opacity: 1
    }),
    stagger(150, [
      animate('0.6s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)',
        style({
          transform: 'translateX(100%)',
          opacity: 0
        }))
    ])
  ])
```